# How to delete a Template on a Button click

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, controltemplate

i have `ControlTemplate`, which is used as a resource inside a `ListBox`, i am trying to delete the template i.e remove it totally from `ListBox` on a `Button` click
here is the code for template

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="tasktemplate1">
            <Canvas Height="50" Width="850">
                <Label Content="{Binding XPath=task[1]/name}"  Height="30" Width="170" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="150" Background="LightGray">
                </Label>
                <TextBox Height="30" Width="120" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="370" Background="AliceBlue"></TextBox>
                <Label Canvas.Left="500" Canvas.Top="10">$</Label>
                <Button Click="deletebuttonclick" Canvas.Top="12" Height="10" Width="30" Canvas.Left="600" ></Button>
            </Canvas>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

here is the code for `ListBox`

```
 <TabItem>
        <Canvas Height="700" Width="850">
            <ListBox  x:Name="listBox" Height="700" Width="850">
                <ListBoxItem DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource TaskList}}" Template="{StaticResource tasktemplate1}"/>
            </ListBox>
        </Canvas>
    </TabItem>
```

and the code behind is for the `Button` click

```
    private void deletebuttonclick(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       var r=listBox.FindResource("tasktemplate1");
       listBox.Items.Remove(r);
    }
```

where am i going wrong,help needed,thanx.

Comment: what do you expect to happen when you remove template?

Comment: it must be removed from the listbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**ControlTemplate**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is just visual representation of control that how it will look like.

So, you need to **remove the item** (**`ListBoxItem`**) from the Items collection and not Template. Since templated control is removed, template automatically will be removed.

```
private void deletebuttonclick(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   listBox.Items.RemoveAt(0);
   // listBox.Items.Clear(); OR in case want to clear all listBoxItems, use Clear
}
```